# How to create a checklist in MS Access that changes conditional formating

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, conditional-formatting

I am building a database for maintenance performed on lighting fixtures, each with their own unique serial number. I already have an excel document with all this data, but want to create a better system for managing the data.

The idea is that every time I service a unit, I have a new job #, and fill out a checklist and enter notes for that job.  I have created a Job # table, with columns for serial #, date received, date completed, notes etc.  I have also created a job form, which includes all the relevant info for that job#.  The question I have now is how to create relatively efficient checklists that modify the background color of a text field.

For the first part of this, I need to have a drop down list with different model lights to choose from(each light has different feature sets to test), which, depending on which model I select, will display/generate a checklist, with about 25 items, that is unique to that model.
Then, when all the check boxes are checked for that specific checklist, I need the background color of a text field("Unit Good?") to change from red to green.  These check lists need to be specific to the job #/record #, and I'm curious if there's a relatively easy/efficient way to do this.

At present I have about 150 jobs, and it will only increase over time. 
My preference is to avoid VBA if possible, but if necessary, some pointers, or recommended tutorials would be highly useful.

I've built the underlying table and form, but haven't yet been able to figure out how to do the checklists.

Any help here would be extremely appreciated.  I am happy to provide any additional information/documents if necessary.

Comment: Cross post http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=76493

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible and it can be done without VBA (although macros are required).

1. First, you need to create a couple more tables. I'm making the assumption that you only work on one light model per job (multiple models is possible but more complex). You will need to create three tables (two if you already have a table for your light models).

   - Light_Models will contain information about the light models you service, including their unique serial number.
   - Model_Checklist_Defaults will contain default checklist values for each light model
   - Job_Checklist will contain checklist values for a specific job based on the light model you serviced (this is where multiple light models in a job would add complexity). When you create a job for a specific light model, you need to copy the appropriate values from Model_Checklist_Defaults into Job_Checklist (this can be done by creating a query and calling it from a macro, I won't cover this here).

These tables need to be related in the following way [Relationships image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5ZoN.png). I only included the bare minimum columns, you could add more as you need.

2. You need to create a form to present your checklist, and optionally, other job details. This form assumes that you have already created a job and selected a light model, but you could modify the form to create the job and checklist in one step.

   The example form ([Form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q9W4.png)) has a jobNumber textbox that identifies the current job, a coloredField whose background color changes based on the checklist, and a subform that presents data in the Job_Checklist table filtered by the jobNumber textbox (this filtering is with linked fields in the subform [Property image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO3rI.png)).
3. The final piece is configuring the coloredField background color and setting a macro on the form, jobNumber and subform to update the coloredField when checkboxes are clicked/unclicked.

   This macro need to be set in several places ([Macro image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktz3p.png)):

   - Form OnLoad event: this ensures that the coloredField updates based on the checklist when the form opens (in case you close and reopen, for example)
   - jobNumber AfterUpdate event: this field updates the checklist subform when its value changes, so you have to recheck the checklist values each time
   - subform OnExit event: this event is called after you have clicked into the subform (checking a box, for example) and then clicked on another field in the main form. This event catches the actual checkbox changes.

Comment: First off, thank you so much for taking the time to really dig into this and build a test db. I can't tell you how much I appreciate your willingness to help here.  
That being said, I do have a few questions/comments.  
First off, just to clarify, each job # only contains one unique light fixture, and so only one model/checklist.
On to your recommendations. I’m confused by the use of the Light Models table.  Its just confusing to me the way we're thinking about this, as model numbers don't have a unique serial number, but rather, unique serial numbers have model numbers that are duplicated

Comment: Currently my Job # List table has the Job #’s, serial #’s and all the notes from that specific job.  Can I not simply add a multi-value drop down field to my job Form?  This could contain the model names, and could be bound to the job # list table.
If I understand correctly, then couldn’t I then have a macro fire when that selection is made, to then load the correct checklist table or subform into my form? This starts to get confusing to me when thinking about how to keep the selected/completed checklist values bound to that specific job, without overwriting another jobs checklist values.

Comment: I'm wondering if it would be a bad choice to have some 30 or 40 additional columns of yes/no fields for each job in my job # list table that would be toggled by a checkbox in my job form. In this method, I would, I think, have to have the correct subform checklist populate the job form, and then have those checkboxes only toggle values for that job # row in my job #list table. In this method, I would include all checklist items for all models on every job row, but the conditional formatting rules would have to only listen to the relevant items for that model. Is any of this possible/advisable?

Comment: The reason for the Light_Models table is to uniquely identify each model, so that you can manage default checklist items in Model_Checklist_Default. You are right, however, that each model will have multiple serial numbers associated with it, so I was a little backwards there.

Comment: You could use a dropdown to display values from your Light_Models table. To keep it simple, you would probably want a button next to the dropdown that generated the  checklist  after you select a model (prevents duplicates). The Job_Checklist table addresses your concern about overwriting another job's checklist. This table uses the JobNumber and Checkbox_ID to uniquely identify each required checkbox. So instead of having a bunch of ambiguous checkbox columns in your Job#List table, you store checkboxes and values in another table and display them via a subform.

Comment: The button macro would copy values associated with the selected model from Model_Checklist_Default into Job_Checklist and assign the applicable JobNumber to each record.